# How to get the 'yesterday' business day in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a query that gets the yesterday records, but I want that in monday I be able to get the records from friday, not sunday.

Here what I have so far:

```
select * from tb_interaction
where
(DateInteraction >= DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 1, GETDATE()), 0)) AND      
(DateInteraction < DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, GETDATE()), 0))
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Bingle SQL Server calendar table.  Create permanent calendar table with a row for each date.  Each row can have attributes to identify a business or non-business day, along with other information like fiscal periods, making queries like this simple and extensible.

Answer (score 1):

If your settings are set for English, then you can do:

```
select i.*
from tb_interaction i cross join
     (select (case when datename(getdate()) = 'Monday' then 3
                   when datename(getdate()) = 'Sunday' then 2
                   else 1
              end) as diff
     ) x
where DateInteraction >= dateadd(day, - diff - 1, cast(getdate() as date)) and
      DateInteraction < dateadd(day, - diff, cast(getdate() as date))
```